How to open multiple URLs in Appsheet
My scenario is I'm working on an Application which has a list of URLs in a table in appsheet, we are showing them as a table view. I'm trying to add a functionality for selecting multiple rows in that table view and then have a behavior of opening them in new tabs.
I looked at behaviors related multiple role edits and all, I also looked at different functions like select and all but couldn't come up with a solution.
Any direction or hint of making this possible helps.

Try using an action of type Data: execute an action on a set of rows with the selected rows as the target and the referenced action one of type External: go to a website.

Hi Steve, thank you so much for the answer, how do I pass the website link to External: go to a website action? How do I pass the selected rows?
